# Is there any method for getting expiry date of ssl certificate in Perl?

Tags: perl, ssl-certificate

I use LWP::UserAgent, Date::Parse,Net::SSLeay qw(get_https3) for expiry date of ssl certificate it gives me 3 dates in which 1 is correct

I tried this method for fetching dates but it gives me 3 dates for this where one is correct and for other dates it gives wrong dates total I have to get dates of 20 urls it gives me 3 correct date and other are wrong and also it gives me 2-3 dates for per url

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
 ssl_opts => {
    SSL_verify_callback => sub {
        my ($ok, $ctx_store) = @_;
        my $cert = Net::SSLeay::X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert($ctx_store);
        print Net::SSLeay::P_ASN1_TIME_get_isotime(
            Net::SSLeay::X509_get_notAfter($cert) ), "\n";
            
        return $ok;
    },
 },
);
my $url  = 'https://pjf.nif.org/m/login';
```

I want a perfect date as shown in certification option on any url and

Answer (score 1):

For the URL that you show in your example, there are three certificates: the root certificate from USERTrust, the intermediate certificate from Sectigo, and the website certificate. The dates correspond to the expiration of each of those. [The Difference Between Root Certificates and Intermediate Certificates](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/root-certificates-intermediate/) is a good read.

You likely want the closest date, which should be the expiry of the user certificate.